# Vim can't find C++ libavformat/libavutil library (No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, c, vim, ld

Loading up the [omxplayer.cpp](https://github.com/pukster/omxplayer/blob/master/OMXReader.cpp) file in vim and it gives me the following error:

> omxplayer.cpp|34 col 34| fatal error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory

This is where the problem is occurring

```
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
```

But I know the files exist:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libavu*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 2013-11-08 13:46 /usr/lib/libavutil.so -> /usr/lib/libavutil.so.51.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 2012-06-13 12:38 /usr/lib/libavutil.so.51 -> libavutil.so.51.7.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117212 2012-06-13 12:38 /usr/lib/libavutil.so.51.7.0
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libavf*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      30 2013-11-08 13:29 /usr/lib/libavformat.so -> /usr/lib/libavformat.so.53.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 2012-06-13 12:38 /usr/lib/libavformat.so.53 -> libavformat.so.53.3.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053000 2012-06-13 12:38 /usr/lib/libavformat.so.53.3.0
```

And `ldconfig` can also find them:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libavformat && ldconfig -p | grep libavutil
libavformat.so.53 (libc6, hwcap: 0x0008000000008000) => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libavformat.so.53
libavformat.so.53 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libavformat.so.53
libavutil.so.51 (libc6, hwcap: 0x0008000000008000) => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libavutil.so.51
libavutil.so.51 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libavutil.so.51
```

I have read somewhere that ldconfig is for run time whereas ld is for build time, however, in this case I know the libraries are there in /usr/lib, therefore, what could be causing this problem?

Comment: fatal error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory, nothing to do with ld, you have a missing header file

Comment: @how can I check to see if it's there or not? `cat /usr/lib/libavormat.so` =P And how do I get it?

Comment: Sounds out of scope, it depends of your linux distro, for example, for debian you need to install libavformat-dev, which include the .h file.

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/libavformat-dev/filelist : /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h

Comment: Also, I don't think this question should be tagged with vim.  If willl's solution worked, please add it as an answer and close too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
omxplayer.cpp|34 col 34| fatal error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory
```

Error message says all: It is not in library, But it is header file which is not found.
 Normal location is `/usr/include/libavformat`.

first check by command whether header location is included by `g++ -v omxplayer.cpp`, This command will show what all directories are included for header files.

if it dows not show directory containing specified header then you need to specify it's location in `g++ -Ipath/to/headers omxplayer.cpp.` command.

Comment: But how would I instruct `vim` to do that `g++ -Ipath/to/headers omxplayer.cpp` command